# Combining Unicode Characters in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, unicode

I am trying to get Illustrator to display my unicode font correctly (i.e. the way every other program is displaying it). I am currently using the Noto font, which I know can display all the characters I need.

The character I'm having an issue with is: ı̨ (dotless i with ogonek).
As far as I can tell, this is created by combining U+0131 and U+0328.

[image: This is what it looks like in Excel/Word/notepad/etc.]

Illustrator only seems to output the dotless i (U+0131) without the ogonek. In the glyph panel, I can access the i *with* the dot and the ogonek (U+012f), but that is ultimately not the character I need.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I have same question - this came up in the AI scripting forums and I have found the same: it doesn't do combined characters but it does to single characters which are "pre-combined".

Comment: This might be a silly question, but is there a difference between the character that you need and U+012e? That is available in Noto Sans and they look the same to my ignorant, English eyes. :-)

Comment: @Chris +012e is a *capital* i+ogonek, OP wants a dotless i (which is just a lowercase i without the dot)

Comment: @rbhamjee is the problem only that they aren't combining correctly? I can't get them to combine but I can place both glyphs and negatively kern to get them to combine ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLyOb.png))

Comment: @Cai When I try to adjust the kerning it doesn't actually change for me (I cannot seem to place the cursor between the i and the ogonek). I can make it look correct with tracking, but that doesn't really work when the character is used in a word.

Answer (score 2):

I honestly have no idea what's going on here. I can't get them to combine correctly from direct input at all but I could get them to combine correctly by pasting an ogonek directly before the dotless i... then two minutes later I try again and it doesn't work.

It's not ideal but as a workaround you can simply kern both glyphs to the correct position. Again, Illustrator is doing some weird things here; sometimes I can kern the glyphs (after inputing them directly after one another) with no problem and sometimes they're instantly combined and treated as a single character (although not visually)... So a workaround for the workaround; input the glyphs with a space between and kern from there.

So you input; ogonek + space + dotless i (the blue square is just the indicator for the space with "Show Hidden Characters" on):

[image]

And kern (I turned off "Show Hidden Characters" and placed a regular i+ogonek for reference):

[image]

Not ideal, but a workaround if you're really stuck and can't figure out a proper fix.

Comment: Following your exact workflow, I can create the character. Interestingly, if I try to paste that character into a word, it loses the ogonek. If use the workflow in the word, it will work, albeit with slightly tight spacing to the left.

Comment: It's certainly strange, I can't even get consistent behaviour within Illustrator without the space between